# Customize menu local task links

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I am looking for a way to customize 'edit', 'view', 'delete' links.

I use bootstrap theme, but i use bootstrap v4 styles for it. I want to add 'nav-link' class to each link.

And find a way to display somewhere, not just below post title.

I couldnt find a tutorial about it. Where should i look for this? template parts (twig) or themename.theme file?

Answer (score 2):

For preprocess function you can use **`HOOK_preprocess_menu_local_tasks(&$variables) {...`** where **`HOOK`** is the name of your active theme.

And for template suggestions you need to enable debugging and see with inspect element, as usual it must be `menu-local-tasks.html.twig`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the local tasks using menu-local-tasks.html.twig and menu-local-task.html.twig. The Stable core theme has samples of these files. You could also try using hook_preprocess_menu(&$vars) in your .theme file. I'm not sure if it processes the local menu items though. I am using it for the main menu.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own tpl.php! I think there should be a template file within your bootstrap theme. Copy that file to your subtheme templates folder and edit it the way you want it to look like.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell that I user drupal 8. which tpl file should I work on it? I can find drupal 8 version of that

Comment: Sorry, I don't have used Drupal 8 yet - shame on me! But I would guess, that the template concept is still working. You could search for page.tpl.php (the whole page) or node.tpl.php (template for nodes).

Search the bootstrap theme folder for a folder called templates, I guess, there you'll find these files!

Comment: Just had a look at bootstrap for Drupal 8. The concept seems to be the same as for Drupal 7 but the tpl.php - files now are the twig files!

Comment: which tpl file should i look for?

Comment: you could have a look at page.html.twig, node.html.twig or the menu-local-task.html.twig / menu-local-tasks.html.twig